# create view in postgresql containing table with many2many field

Tags: python, postgresql, database-view

I created a view containing some audit attributes:

```
class audit_performance(osv.Model):
_name = "audit.performance"
_auto = False
_description = "Audit performance Analysis"
_inherit = ["audit", "action"]

def init(self, cr):
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'audit_performance')
    cr.execute("""
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW audit_performance AS (
            SELECT
                c.id,
                c.name,
                count(c.id) as nbr_cases,
                c.date_begin ,
                c.date_end ,
                c.user_id,
                c.audit_leader,
                c.audit_type,
                c.state as audit_state,
                c.company_id,
                a.state as action_state
            FROM
                audit c, action a
            GROUP BY c.id
        )""")
```

and I created a graph view to see the performance of audits, everything works fine but not when I add action state (I changed to one2many field but it doesn't work).

this is the audit model:

```
class audit(orm.Model):
    _name = "audit"
    _description = "Audit"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _columns = {
       'name': fields.char('Name', size=50),
       'imp_opp_ids': fields.one2many(
        'action',
        'audit_id',
        'Related Actions',
    ),}
```

it doesn't work, it doesn't recognise the field although it does exist in the model.
this is the error message:

```
relation "action" does not exist
```

The objective is to classify the audits by state of its actions (audits with all actions are closed or not yet closed ...) and have an idea of treadet audits.

Comment: 0) add a semicolon to the end. 1) `... FROM mgmtsystem_audit c, mgmtsystem_action a` do you *really* want a Carthesian product? 2) GROUP BY implies that all non-grouped selected fields are aggregates.

Comment: My advice: start by doing toy-problems before doing any real work.

Comment: Post the exact error message and the table's definition.